# Angular HttpClient how to pass results to the template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and COMPLETELY missing something here. Ive set up a component to make a get request following the docs and some help from a previous post here :) Now I am missing how to pass the results out to the template?

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss']
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

test = 'test';
results: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    interface ItemsResponse {
      results: string[];
    }

    this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('assets/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }

}
```

and my template is pretty simple:

```
<p>results</p>
<p>{{test}}</p>
<p>
  {{results}}
</p>
```

It seems that making the transition from learning angularjs to angular is making me bang my head against the wall here!

**JSON format:**

```
[
    {
        "pk": "wGR",
        "created": "2017-10-07T01:42:25.110747Z",
        "email_domain": "domain.com",
        "sender_name": null,
        "sender_email": "jobsearch@domain.com",
        "has_user_viewed": false,
        "is_shielded": false
    }
]
```

Comment: what do you see in the console.log? that said, you should initialize results as an empty array to avoid undefined issues: `results: string[] = []`. That said, this template itself won't do much, what was the original goal? In any case, the template updates itself **automatically** in that case, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: console is just showing as undefined...

Comment: 1: results:Array<string>2: {{results | json}} you will get your response json array. It's only to run simply

Comment: @SandraWillford what is the structure of your `email_list.json`?

Comment: @LLai i added it to my original post

Comment: @SandraWillford your json is an array, so you will have to access the data by index. `this.results = data[0]`; As others have mentioned this data won't do much in your current template, you should see something like `[object Object]`. You could use the json pipe to display it `<p>{{results | json}}</p>`

Comment: What console.log(data) gives you?

Comment: @ChauTran it logs the full object payload

Comment: Think I have this solved now. I need just this.results = data and then loop the results in my template?

Comment: @SandraWillford correct, you could store the array and load it into your template with ngFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

    test = 'test';
    results: Array<string> = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        interface ItemsResponse {
            results: string[];
        }

        this.http.get<ItemsResponse>('assets/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
            this.results = data.json();
            console.log(this.results);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(24,35): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'ItemsResponse'.

Comment: with the HttpClient you do not need to parse the response with `.json()`. The issue is something else